# Rsync -e option to ssh

Tags: ssh, rsync

I've been trying to find if the -e option is necessary? Am I not ssh-ing without it by simply doing `user@server` when running rsync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not needing to consider the `rsync` protocol itself, this depends on the compilation options used for your version of `rsync`.

It used to be the case that `rsync` used the `rsh` protocol by default (unless the build-time default had been changed), but the build-time default changed to `ssh` in 2004.

If you're in doubt, start the `rsync` process transferring a relatively large file (or collection of files), and in another terminal run `ps -ef | grep '[r]sync'`. This will show you whether or not you're using `ssh` for a transport. Here's an example from one of my servers, which clearly shows the `ssh` transport:

```
root     28057 27173  1 09:48 pts/4    00:00:00 rsync -avHP --dry-run /home roaima@otherserver:
root     28058 28057  0 09:48 pts/4    00:00:00 ssh -l roaima otherserver rsync --server -vnlHogDtpre.iLsfx --partial . .
```

Finally, be aware that the compilation default can be overridden with the `RSYNC_RSH` environment variable. (See the man page for further details.)

Answer (score 2):

`-e` is for when you want a remote shell *other than* the default `ssh`. `rsync` uses `ssh` as transport by default, but can use any remote shell (with a couple restrictions*), it doesn't care *how* it connects to a remote server.

* The remote shell you use must behave like a shell. It must interpret its zeroeth argument as the destination, and every following argument as a command to execute; the command rsync passes over the remote shell is a `rsync --server …` command, which starts an rsync server on the remote end. It must also attach its **STDIN** to the command's **STDIN**, and the command's **STDOUT** to **STDOUT**, so that rsync and the rsync server can communicate over the remote shell.